# NVidia driver libraries in nvidia/cuda image

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, nvidia-docker, cuvid

I want to run ffmpeg with cuvid hw-accelerated decoding in the container based on official `nvidia/cuda` image. Ffmpeg is not able to find libnvcuvid.so, although there are all required cuda libs.
The output of `ldconfig -p | grep libnv` from the container:

```
libnvrtc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvrtc.so
libnvrtc-builtins.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvrtc-builtins.so
libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.1
libnvidia-opencl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
libnvidia-ml.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so.1
libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.390.12 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.390.12
libnvidia-compiler.so.390.12 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-compiler.so.390.12
libnvidia-cfg.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-cfg.so.1
libnvgraph.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvgraph.so
libnvblas.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvblas.so
libnvToolsExt.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvToolsExt.so
```

Should I just copy `libnvcuvid.so` from the host? Wouldn't it break if underlying driver version changes?

Comment: Are you sure you compiled ffmpeg with `--enable-cuda` `--enable-cuvid` options? As for `ldd` concerned. I believe ffmpeg libraries uses run time binding (dynload) so those libs may not show up on `ldd` listing.

Comment: @thekamilz The code perfectly works on the host system with hw decoding. I load the decoder in the following way `avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("h264_cuvid"))`. Although I have compiled ffmpeg only with `--enable-cuvid` Is `--enable-cuda` mandatory? Maybe I should try it too...

Comment: yes please try it, and I assume you already installed Nvidia video codec SDK to your system: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/531#issuecomment-343993909). Just need to pass env variable `ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES video,compute,utility` or `-e NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=compute,utility,video`. Now I have all required libs `ldconfig -p | grep libnv`:

```
libnvrtc.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvrtc.so.9.0
libnvrtc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvrtc.so
libnvrtc-builtins.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvrtc-builtins.so.9.0
libnvrtc-builtins.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvrtc-builtins.so
libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.1
libnvidia-opencl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
libnvidia-ml.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so.1
libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.390.30 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.390.30
libnvidia-encode.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-encode.so.1
libnvidia-compiler.so.390.30 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-compiler.so.390.30
libnvidia-cfg.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-cfg.so.1
libnvgraph.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvgraph.so.9.0
libnvgraph.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvgraph.so
libnvcuvid.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvcuvid.so.1
libnvblas.so.9.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvblas.so.9.0
libnvblas.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvblas.so
libnvToolsExt.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvToolsExt.so.1
libnvToolsExt.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvToolsExt.so
```